# Schemamigration: adding a simple Null field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

Okay, so I had an app called locationmanager with a model that looks like this:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
```

and I want to change it to this

```
class Location(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, blank=True, null=True)
```

So I ran a schemamigration and received the following:

```
$ python manage.py schemamigration locationmanager --auto
 ? The field 'Location.region' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
 ? Since you are making this field nullable, you MUST specify a default
 ? value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
 ?  1. Quit now.
 ?  2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
 ?  3. Disable the backwards migration by raising an exception; you can edit the migration to fix it later
 ? Please select a choice:
```

This is confusing to me. And yes I have read the south docs.

1. Firstly, why is it saying `'Location.region' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.` The alterations I made to the field ARE making it the case that it is null, what gives? An explanation would be great.
2. Why do I need to specify a default? Once I specify this default where does it live? In an SQL table? Does this matter if I have existing data or is this simply for the scheme itself?

3.I sort of understand option 1,2 but what exactly would option 3 do? Why is it useful?

Thank you tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

Because migrations work both way. One day you may want to rollback to the state it was before and in that case you'll need a default value for the mandatory field.

Oh, and in this case I usually always choose option *2* and enter `0` as the value. Works fine.

Comment: I see, but how can you add `0` for a foreign key? doesn't that not make much sense?

Comment: It doesn't, but I do this because ForeignKey can be passed a number and `0` is rarely the `pk` of an existing model. If you don't think you'll be rolling back, choose option `3`.